# My freq-dist function keeps coming up undefined (python nltk) 3.4

Tags: python, nlp

I'm doing NLP with Python 3.4, and my frequency distribution function keeps returning as undefined, even after I call on "import nltk..." I appreciate any help. I am not having any other issues. I have Windows 7, 64 bit
Here is the code:

```
from nltk.book import *
text1
Out[39]: <Text: Moby Dick by Herman Melville 1851>
fdist1 = FreqDist(text1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-a9ccb6c27929> in <module>()
----> 1 fdist1 = FreqDist(text1)

NameError: name 'FreqDist' is not defined

fdist1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-f986ce66c258> in <module>()
----> 1 fdist1

NameError: name 'fdist1' is not defined
```

Comment: Please post a full stack trace and show us which line in the code triggers the error.

Comment: You're not defining it correctly. It's not used by doing `import ntl` only. Post full code as said by @Tal

Comment: OK, I have just made an edit which includes the code

Answer (score 0):

```
import nltk

text1 = nltk.book.text1
fdist1 = nltk.FreqDist(text1)

print(fdist1)
```

Result:

```
<FreqDist with 19317 samples and 260819 outcomes>
```